# How do I upload images in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, upload, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I upload images to go into `~/Content/Images` in ASP.NET MVC 3.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading an image using ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379558/uploading-an-image-using-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload images in ASP.NET MVC, try these questions:

- [Simple Image Upload in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891522/simple-image-upload-in-aspnet-mvc)
- [Uploading an image in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379558/uploading-an-image-using-asp-net-mvc)

If you're wanting to use an ASP.NET control to upload images, that breaks the separation of concerns for MVC.  There are [upload helpers available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304617/html-helper-for-input-type-file).

Answer (score 2):

**HTML Upload File ASP MVC 3.**

**Model**: (*Note that FileExtensionsAttribute is available in MvcFutures. It will validate file extensions client side and server side.*)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required, Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FileExtensions(Extensions = "csv", ErrorMessage = "Specify a CSV file. (Comma-separated values)")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML View**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)
}
```

**Controller action**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Use your file here
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```