# Can't get MVC 4 FileExtensions Attribute to work on ViewModel property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I need to upload a csv file and I want to restrict it's extension to .csv

So I added the follow property to my ViewModel:

```
[FileExtensions(ErrorMessage = "Must choose .csv file.",Extensions = "csv,txt")]
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

In my view I have the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)
```

However as soon as it hits my "ModelState.IsValid" check it returns invalid with my error message of "Must choose .csv file."

I assume I'm just missing a parameter, but I haven't found a sample of this in use any where yet.

Comment: How can you upload a file using a Textbox in your View ? Because i never tried it like that. I've used `<input type="file"..` to do that

Comment: @Karthik Fair question. When it generates the html you get `<input type="file"` and that part works. If I remove the validation constraint the file is uploaded as expected.

Comment: What's this `FileExtensions` attribute? Where is it coming from? That's not something that's built-in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It's a new attribute in .net 4.5 [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192365.aspx) and it seems it is not working with MVC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536589/asp-net-mvc-3-dataannotations-fileextensionsattribute-not-working

Comment: @nemesv, good point. I didn't know about that attribute. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I saw that question, but wasn't sure it was exactly the same problem. I was originally driven to this version based on another question that used MVC Futures in MVC 3.0 to do the same thing. So that is why I made the assumption that it was supported in .net 4.5 MVC 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is that the FileExtensionsAttribute works only on string variables. The easiest way to check the file extension of HttpPostedFileBase variable is to use [this simple attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650754/1838837). It solved my problem.

The only downside is that this new attribute is only validated on serverside so don't forget to check the model state with:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  // Do the work
}
```