# Uploading a file with filtering its extension

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, razor

I have an ASP.Net web application in which i have to upload a file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading_validation", "Super", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="dossier"  accept="*.iso, *.rar, *.zip"/>
   <br />
    @Html.Label("Date d'expiration")

    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="duree" />
    <br />
 <input type="submit" value="OK" />
 }
```

I'd like accept just the extensions `accept="*.iso, *.rar, *.zip"`, but it didn't work.

Why does this filter not work? How can i modify the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the FileExtensions to achieve this:

```
[Required, FileExtensions(Extensions=".iso,.rar,.zip", ErrorMessage="Incorrect file format")]
```

Add Dossier to your model to pass it back to the view and render it like this:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dossier, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dossier)
```

It should validate both client and server-side.

Comment: I'm using MVC 4 for a project and this solution invalid not matter my extension is correct or not. Finally solved the issue by [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536589/asp-net-mvc-3-dataannotations-fileextensionsattribute-not-working/13650754#13650754)
Hope that help people stuck at old version like me.

Answer (score 3):

`accept`  attribute don't supported by all of browsers. You can't rely on client side and should filter files in action.

BTW, you should use this attribute this way:

```
accept="application/iso,application/rar,application/zip"
```

Upd: in other way you can validate file extension with javascript: [look at sample](http://jsfiddle.net/A7pfs/)

Comment: yes i filtered it in the action, and i need to be in the view

Comment: Seems crome don't supports this **correct** MIME types. This markup accord to [W3C spec](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)

Answer (score 3):

this snippet seems to be acceptable by all browsers

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading_validation", "Super", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <input type="file" name="dossier"   accept=".rar , .zip"/>
   <br />
    @Html.Label("Date d'expiration")

    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="duree" />
    <br />
 <input type="submit" value="OK" />
 }
```